# Css Border hover image effect

Tags: html, css, hover, border, css-transitions

I'm trying to apply an hover effect above an image in a wordpress theme.
The effect should show a border and a background with a text.
The problem is that the border is wider and higher than the image and I cannot understand why.
I've tried many solution but the result is always the same: the border appears only in my top and left side. I'm going crazy....

Here's the link at my page:

http://boscolo.dm-cloud.net/

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance,
Francesco

Comment: Quick guess would be your image is larger than your surrounding div and this div has fixed dimensions? Try overflow:hidden on your surrounding div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code

```
.topImage2 .bordo {
    border: 0 solid #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 78;
}
```

You just have to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.topImage2 .bordo`

Comment: Yes! You're right! Thanks so much, I have to learn so much things about css :)